# Converting System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image to System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, image, webui

I can't seem to convert it. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are two completely different objects:

- `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` is a control that has the ability to render HTML which will make the browser download and display an appointed image
- `System.Drawing.Image` is a class that has the ability to load an image into memory for manipulating it, or to display it in a control (but not the web image control).

So unfortunately there is no way you can convert a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` to a `System.Drawing.Image`; it doesn't even touch the image data.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image is merely a container for any valid image file specified by the ImageUrl property. If you would like to take the image at the ImageUrl and convert it to a System.Drawing.Image you can call `System.Drawing.Image.ImageFromFile("path/to/image")`.