# How to set System.Drawing.Image to System.ui.WebControls.Image in datalist template item

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, system.drawing

I am making a Bookstore website. I use Visual Studio 2010 and MS SQL Database. I have images about books. I have a Book table  in database and there is an image column in this table.

I saved these images (in byte array format) in database.

I tested it in Windows Form Application and everything is ok. I mean i can retrieve and save images to/from database. when I retrieve them from database, i save them (in System.Drawing.Image format) in Book class.

```
    public Book
    {
          private int id;
          private System.Drawing.Image image;
          // name and other .. informations,  constructor, get and set methods;
    }

    public BookLayer
    {
           // after call this method i can get all informations from database
           public static List<Book> getBooks()
           {
            }
    }
```

I use datalist with objectdatasource in Asp.net 4 Web Project. I wrote Book and BookLayer class for objectdatasource. I can show all informations in datalist except image.
because image is System.Drawing.Image in Book class but image is System.ui.WebControls.Image which in datalist template item. Format is different. How can i do that ?  is that way wrong ? Pls give me any advice.

Comment: You can use handler (.ashx) to display image

Comment: Question has been asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357826/converting-system-web-ui-webcontrols-image-to-system-drawing-image) with the short answer that you can't convert from System.Drawing.Image to WebControls.Image because you try to convert an image resource into an HTML control. Best would be to write a load routine to retrieve image information from database and use this in your application as stated [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1767962.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use handler. You can do as Add a template field

```
 <ItemTemplate>
<img border="2" width="150px" src="../images/loading.gif" onload="getpic(this,'<%# Eval("bkid")%>');"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

use the following java script
    function getpic(img, pid) {

```
try {
img.onload = null;
img.src = '../Getimage.ashx?id=' + pid;
} catch (e) {
alert(e);
}
}
</script>
```

in your getimage.ashx

```
byte[] imageBytes = ;// ToDOget your byte
            Bitmap newBmp = ConvertToBitmap(imageBytes);
            if (newBmp != null)
            {
                newBmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                newBmp.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks all of you especially SaschaM78, I followed your advices and I did it using handler as described on this site http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html